# Copying each rows values into column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |  |  |  |

I want to convert the data frame into something similar to:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

Basically copying each row into column values. Not Transposing the rows and columns.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying of a dataframe is numpy array. Use the reshape.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(1,-1)))
```